# Lights flickering

Tags: gfci, neutral, solar

I have a off grid solar system with 110-120v pure sine inverter. All my outlets work with power but GFCI blinks red every min or so and my all my LED lights flicker when on. I feel like I'm not getting the full 110-120v or the current is dropping for some reason. Again the whole house has power and I use all my outlets but the lights flickering concerns me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What make and model is your inverter?

Comment: What does your voltmeter say? If you are on an off-grid solar system and you don't own a voltmeter, you should get one. For that matter, what GFCI, and what does its documentation say WRT "blinking Red" - GFCIs are not at all consistent about what indicators do or mean, so that could be "all happy and good" or "everything's terrible and bad" depending on GFCI. Plug in a GFCI tester and see if it trips as it should...

Comment: Also, off-grid solar systems that have an AC inverter are often infested with *really terrible, cringeworthy* AC distribution... gosh, as if they were done by people whose specialty is off-grid solar DC systems and not AC power!  You may be witnessing side-effects of a much bigger problem ... a review of the overal distribution and system bonding wouldn't hurt.